# I don't receive my test mail to my e-mail address using JavaMail

Tags: java, email, outlook, smtp

I want to be able to send a mail to a given recipient if I click a button. I wrote a class MailBean for that but it does not seem to work because I never receive the mail to my e-mail address. I tested my code with the debugger and everything seems fine except I don't receive anything, not even in the spam folder.

I work with `outlook.com` as host.

Here is my class.

```
    public class MailBean {

    private final String USERNAME = "htlplus@outlook.com"; //the sender
    private final String PASSWORD = "*******";

    public Object sendMessage() {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);
        prop.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp-mail.outlook.com");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(prop, new Authenticator() {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
            }
        });

        try {
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("htlplus@outlook.com"));
            message.setRecipients(
                    Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("andor98@gmail.com"));
            message.setSubject("Mail Subject");

            String msg = "This is my first email using JavaMailer";

            MimeBodyPart mimeBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            mimeBodyPart.setContent(msg, "text/html");

            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
            multipart.addBodyPart(mimeBodyPart);

            message.setContent(multipart);

            Transport.send(message);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please tell me how to allow less secure apps in my outlook account? I've been googling for 10 minutes and can't seem to find the answer.

And I'm using SMTP not IMAP.

Comment: Check this, https://www.outlook-apps.com/outlook-com-pop-settings/

Comment: And this https://support.office.com/en-us/article/pop-imap-and-smtp-settings-for-outlook-com-d088b986-291d-42b8-9564-9c414e2aa040

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/server-settings-you-ll-need-from-your-email-provider-c82de912-adcc-4787-8283-45a1161f3cc3